# Identify .json files with empty arrays?

Tags: shell-script, json, jq

I have a folder with multiple .json files. There are certain files with empty arrays, Sample file :

```
{
"WarehouseActivity": []
}
```

The file has no other data apart from the one shown above.

I need to identify these files and move them into a error folder. Any suggestions on how to go about this would be great.

Thanks,
Kavin

Comment: is key `WarehouseActivity` common/same for all the files?

Comment: Did you try with `jq`?

Comment: `{ "x": [[],[]] }` would have an array made of two empty arrays. Should that also be flagged?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes its same across all the files and no, i haven't tried the jq option...am gonna try the code posted by you and revert back to you.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas well, there hasn't been any such case yet. Just one empty array.

Comment: @dirkt i wasn't aware of the jq till date, i just installed it on my machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`Jq`** would be the right tool for processing/analyzing *JSON* data:

```
for f in *.json; do
    if jq -e 'keys_unsorted as $keys
              | ($keys | length == 1) 
                and .[($keys[0])] == []' "$f" > /dev/null; then
        mv "$f" error_dir/
    fi
done
```

Comment: this works great! It identifies the empty files and moves them to the error folder. To start with i wasn't even aware of the jq command, i had to install the jq package in my machine to get this to work. Thanks a lot. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy, you're welcome

Comment: Hey! There is a scenario when there is no such file , am getting a error message "jq: error: Could not open file *.json: No such file or directory" . For now am just suppressing it. Any way around it ?

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy, it seems that you are not applying the above approach in exact manner. `for f in *.json;` will iterate through existed `.json` files (unless you don't have folders which end with `.json`)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Well i think i didn't explain myself well. When the folder is completely empty and there are no json files i get the error :jq: error: Could not open file Test_*.json: No such file or directory . I have implemented the exact same code given by you. As a work around i am just check if any file exist and then am running your code. This does't throw any error. Any better way to implement this sir?

Answer (score 10):

```
mkdir -p error_folder &&
for json in ./*.json; do
    if jq -e '.. | select(type == "array" and length == 0)' "$json" >/dev/null
    then
        mv "$json" error_folder/
    fi
done
```

This is more or less the same approach as Roman took in [his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/441775/116858), but uses a different `jq` expression.

The expression `..|select(type == "array" and length == 0)` will recurse the full JSON structure and select all bits of it that are zero-length arrays (anywhere, at any depth).

If the `select()` is successful, then `jq` will exit with a zero exit status (success), which means that the JSON document contains an empty array somewhere (or the file is totally empty).  This triggers a moving of the document to `error_folder` in the script.

---

From comments below it is clear that the user is only interested in the `WarehouseActivity` array.

My code with a modified `jq` expression:

```
mkdir -p error_folder &&
for json in ./*.json; do
    if jq -e '.. | .WarehouseActivity? | select(type == "array" and length == 0)' "$json" >/dev/null
    then
        mv "$json" error_folder/
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that `jq` (at least my version) also returns true here for empty files and files made entirely of blanks (which the OP may also want to consider as errors anyway).

Comment: Hi @Kusalananda , i gave this code a try but it is not working as expected. It ends up moving all the json files in that folder including the empty json file.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy Then all files contain at least one empty array somewhere, or you have an error in your script.  I've tested the code in my answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, you are correct the json files do have empty arrays.  I was looking to identify the json files which have only the below : {
"WarehouseActivity": []
} Don't really want to identify all the empty arrays in the json files. But great solution. I will use this when i need to identify all the empty arrays . Thanks a lot. really appreciate your help.

Comment: @KavinPalaniswamy Updated my answer.